# How to develop Erlang Nitrogen apps in Docker

Tags: erlang, docker, nitrogen

I'm trying to work out an efficient work flow for developing Erlang Nitrogen apps in Docker.

Sans Docker, I would keep two terminals open:

- a bash terminal terminal for making source changes
- a Nitrogen console (erl) for compiling Erlang modules and testing expressions

But I can't find a way to do that in Docker. Attempts to open a second terminal open a new container.

Can some kind soul point the way?

Many thanks,

LRP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [docker-enter](https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter) to enter a running container.

For example, you could do

`-- Terminal 1
$ docker run -it foo bash
container1$ hackhackhack`

`-- Terminal 2
$ docker ps
...
abcd...  foo
$ docker-enter abcd
container1$ hackhackhack`